# need help in deciphering the logs of my bootlooping phone

Tags: adb, boot-loop, logging

I am trying to fix my phone that got stuck at a bootloop. Earlier it died out of battery and rebooted when I plugged it in and went on a bootloop, I did a lot of things between my last reboot and this one and I can't really know exactly which one was the cause f the loop.

I have a custom ROM installed that is a bit on the buggy side, but it did work for me totally fine for months now.

I have captured the looping part of the logs in logcat which I was able to get to using the ADB logcat command on my PC.

I would like to know what was the problem and if there is a quick way to fix it instead of maybe factory reset or wiping all.

here is the debug logs: https://pastebin.com/36j7CFkx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following line looks very suspicious:  `Unable to determine ABI list from property ro.product.cpu.abilist64.'` If such a basic property is not available something is really wrong with your device.

Comment: @Robert what would i need to do to fix it ? i really don't want to reflash